# Inserting an External Link in Page Viewer Webpart in SPS 2013 gives warning

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, external-data, warning

Inserting an External Link in Page Viewer Webpart in SPS 2013 gives warning.

Warning Message: Only Secure content is displayed.

Gives an option to click on a button name: show all content

Please suggest what can be done to get rid of the warning message.

Comment: Check this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/2625928

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning usually occurs if the current page has been hosted within a secure HTTPS environment. Meanwhile, it embeds unsecured HTTP contents/scripts.

In this case, you need to enable display mixed content by following the mentioned steps below

> Open IE browser > Tools > Internet Option > Click on Security tab >
>   Internet > Custom level > Below Miscellaneous section > Enable Display
>   Mixed Content.

Yo can also check the main reference [How to enable display mixed content to avoid “Only Secure Content is displayed” risk within Internet Explorer and “This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources” risk within Goggle Chrome](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/03/only-secure-content-is-displayed-allow-display-mixed-content/)

Comment: Is there an option to not ask yhe user to maje so majy changes. Any server side scripting?

Comment: There's an IRule in load balancer that called SSL - offloading check this article that discuss this point , https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/04/30/the-form-cannot-be-submitted-to-the-web-server-either-because-your-computer-is-offline-or-because-the-host-server-is-currently-unavailable-if-this-problem-persists-contact-your-network-administrator/